# Ignore first two words when reading from a file

Tags: c

My program is reading a txt file that contains some information (name, product, rate, time). I need to copy the last two and write them somewhere else. The code must be in C.

This is what I wrote so far but because of the random length of the first two fields (name, product) it is not working properly.

```
int a=25;
while (!feof(fp)){
    fseek(fp,a,SEEK_SET);
    fgets(ratetime,100,fp);
    fputs(ratetime,fp2);
    a=a+40;     
}
```

Comment: you know the format, just use `fscanf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the format of the file you can just use `fscanf`, like so:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("input_file.txt", "r");
char name[BUFFSIZE];
char product[BUFFSIZE];
int rate;
char time[BUFFSIZE];

while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %s", name, product, rate, time) != EOF)
{
    //copy them in a proper data stucture
}

fclose(fp);
```

EDIT: `BUFFSIZE` is an upper bound for the string size, if you know it. If not, you have read char by char and parse them

Comment: `!= EOF` is not a sufficient check.

Comment: @F_Stain be careful that my answer does NOT provide a complete check while reading lines from the file, as @AnttiHaapala correctly remarked. The condition `!= EOF` checks for the end of file, but you should also check for the number of elements read by `fscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

First, read why *[(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)*.

This can be replaced by using *[fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)* in conjunction with a `while()` loop:

```
fp = fopen(".\\somefilename.txt", "r");
if(fp)
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line, fp))
    {
        // parse line to ignore first two words using strtok() or strchr()
    }
    fclose(fp);
}fclose(fp)
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: @machine_1 - it is an answer.  It suggests two very viable ways to parse a line from a file to eliminate the first two words, as well as warns against a known bad construct.  It is not necessary to implement the solution for an answer, just provide direction on how to address the issue.